# Kendall distribution function of the independence copula

Tags: integration, probability-distributions

Suppose that $U_1,...U_d$ are independent random variables, all uniform on $[0,1]$. 
 For $t \in [0,1]$, can we give an expression for the c.d.f of their product: 
$$F(t) = \mathbb{P}(\prod\limits_{i=1}^d U_i \le t)\text{ ?}$$

I already know that the corresponding p.d.f is $f(t) = \frac{(-1)^{d-1}}{(d-1)!}\ln(t)^{d-1}$, but i need the c.d.f and i cant find a propper expression for it. By IPP i obtained something awfull.

Comment: there is a YouTube giving solution to this ... https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xE0Pp4I7PiA

Comment: Yeah i was hoping for something non-recursive...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $-\ln U_i\sim \text{Exp}(1)$,
$$
Y:=-\sum_{i=1}^d \ln U_i \sim \text{Gamma}(d,1).
$$
Let $X:=\prod_{i=1}^d U_i$. Then for $x\in(0,1)$,
$$
\mathsf{P}(X\le x)=\mathsf{P}(Y\ge -\ln x)=\sum_{k=1}^{d-1}\frac{x(-\ln x)^k}{k!}.
$$

Comment: Very eleguant. Thanks a lot this is exactly what i needed.